# Alias a single field while selecting all(*) fields in mySQL

Tags: mysql

#### What I want to do:

I would like to retrieve *all* data fields from a `Table` and ALIAS only a single field, called `organizationId` as `id`.

---

**Here is my Query:**

`SELECT * FROM watson_schema.organization`

**The question:**

Is this something possible to do when using the all selector(`*`) or do I need to ditch selecting-all and select all fields individually, aliasing the ones I want.

Comment: @Yossi Thanks, can you post this as an answer when you get some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you basically have two options.

1) Selecting this column twice something like :

```
SELECT t.*,t.organizationID as ID FROM watson_schema.organization t
```

2) You have to ditch selecting all and specify the columns..

```
SELECT col1,col2,organizationID as ID,col4,col5 FROM watson_schema.organization
```